# matrix_basis vs. matrix_local for object parented to bone

Tags: python, matrix

How does `matrix_basis` vs `matrix_local` work for object parented to bones?

Looks like `matrix_local` changes when the armature is animated?

I'm trying to get bone parenting work correctly for the glTF exporter and thinking that maybe it should use `matrix_parent_inverse * matrix_basis` instead for getting object's local matrix, but not sure if that would break other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `matrix_basis` is simply a way to access the pose-bone or objects (location,scale,rotation) properties.

  This is just for convenience - so you don't have to consider if euler/quaternion/axis-angle rotation are used when getting/setting a transformation.
- `matrix_local` is the the objects world-space 4x4 matrix, relative to it's parent, if it has a parent - if the parent is a bone or a vertex, it will be relative to the parent matrix defined by the vertex/bone parent relationship.

Comment: Hmmm something is acting weird then, in latest 2.80 I see `matrix_local` for my object (parented to a bone) changing when the bone is animated, even though the child object doesn't move in relation to the bone

Comment: Ok looks like the change in `matrix_local` are very small (1e-06), so maybe just some math rounding :)